# Outlook Addin - Runtime Error

Tags: tfs, outlook-addin, badimageformatexception

I've built an Outlook Add-in using VS2012 to be deployed to Outlook 2010. The add-in's purpose is to allow users to interact with TFS (work items). Deployment on my developer's machines that run VS2012 works fine. Those without VS2012 and one of my developer's that run VS2010 get the following runtime exception:

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader,
>   Version=11.0.0.0,
>
> ...or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format.
>
> ...at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetServiceT 
>   at TFSLibrary.TFSEngine.get_WorkItemStore()
>
> ...

After much research, it would seem that this is a related to the DataStoreLoader dll being x86 (all other dlls in the manifest are set to MSIL), and requesting the WorkItemStore from the TFS service is causing this exception. All of the computers I've deployed it on are 64-bit. I published using "Any CPU" option for all projects in my solution (I've tried other configs, but they cause the add-in to not load at all due to a runtime error in the installation process).

It seems obvious that those of us with VS2012 have something on our systems that the other computers are lacking (I've tried downloading the TFS Object Model, but that didn't change anything).

Can anyone offer some suggestions as to the cause of the error or what these other machines could be lacking?

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I am struggling with the same problem I am afraid and would like to know if there was an eventual solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues deploying addins when I first started addin development, from my experience this is the advice I can give:

What framework version are you developing for? .Net 3.5, 4.0 or 4.5? My guess is as you are on .Net Framework 4.5 because VS2012 Addin projects default to that.

Whenever I publish an Outlook Addin I add the two following prerequisites:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5

By adding these when the user goes to install your addin it will check if it has these installed and if not it will install them as they are required for .NET 4.5 addins. For the most part uses with Visual Studio 2010 will not get these installed automatically , which may be the missing part they have.

I hope this solved your issue, if not I hope it solves somebody else issue in the future.

Comment: The solution consists of the Outlook Addin project and two library projects, all of which are targeting .Net 4.0. The Outlook Addin project has references to Microsoft.Office.Tools.* (framework 4.0) and "Office.dll" (Visual Studio Tools for Office) and "stdole.dll". Based on this information, can you provide further help?

Comment: When publishing the addin go to the solution properties in VS2012 > Publish > Then click the Prerequisites button. Tick the box for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime. This will install this item on the users computer when they install the addin. As you are referencing Microsoft.Office.Tools you will need this.

Comment: I've got all of the the assemblies for publishing the add-in that you've mentioned copying to the output directory. The add-in actually installs and runs to the point where it needs to interact with the TFS service methods. If not for that, I believe I would have a fully functioning Outlook Addin. As noted in the original post, I believe the problem lies solely with the x86 DataStoreLoader dll. Any interaction with it results in the aforementioned exception.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running on 'Any CPU'

Set the platform target in the project settings to: Any CPU

rather than X64 or X86

Comment: Yes. As I stated, I tried "Any CPU" for all projects in my solution. Additionally, I tried different combinations of "Any CPU", "x86", and "x64", but the add-in failed to load at all due to a runtime error in the install. I'm not sure how to view the exact error from those configs.